# Move Apps from Internal to SD--Android 4.1.2, LGE Optimus F3

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, sd-card, internal

**[MOVED TO ANDROID](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/83020/move-apps-from-internal-to-sd-android-4-1-2-lge-optimus-f3) (if "Android Enthusiasts" is the right one)**

Okay, I have been driving myself absolutely crazy and gone into work aggravated twice in a row trying to fix this damn thing.

For those who don't know, the Optimus F3 has only, like, 2gb of internal space. And because Google's Nexus phones don't have SD card slots for some really weird reason, they decided to just pull the function from Android entirely for a few versions. This includes 4.1.2, the version on my phone.

I have gone through the trouble of rooting my phone and downloading numerous programs to help me hack into this hunk of junk, but I can't for the life of me figure out what to do.

And yes, I have tried App2SD's linking thing, and it doesn't work.

I am 99% sure that you can simply move apps from internal to external storage using the SDK and/or command line or something like that, but I have NO idea how and I've looked all over and found nothing that can really help much.

Could someone PLEASE be so kind as to help this poor guy out and actually be able to use that 8gb SD card I got just for this reason? I have struggled and finally gotten Eclipse working, but have NO idea what to do with it, or if I need it at all. Just please, I'm begging you, ***HELP!!***

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on Android, not SO.

Comment: But wouldn't this work here since it's a question related to programming in a way?

Answer (score 0):

well as far as I know every android phone can move apps to the sd card.
You just have to go to the Settings > Apps > (select the App you want to move)
Then there should be a button which says move to sd card or something like that

If that doesnt work please fomat your sd card th **ext4** and try again :)

Comment: Sorry, this is 4.1.2. That button doesn't even EXIST. Otherwise I would not have gone through all this trouble. They literally made you completely unable to move apps to the SD card. http://i.imgur.com/32O8SDB.png Here's some proof.